# Resource Resolver returned as null via sling models

Tags: java, aem, sling, sling-models

Resource Resolver is being returned as null while injecting through sling models, let me know if anything I am missing :

I tried with :

```
@Model(adaptables = Resource.class)
public class Navigation {

   @Inject  @Source("sling-object")
   private ResourceResolver resourceResolver;

}
```

I also tried with:

```
@Model(adaptables = Resource.class)
public class Navigation {

  @Inject
  private ResourceResolver resourceResolver;

}
```

In both cases it was being returned as null and throwing a null pointer exception.

Let me know what I may be missing to correct this error.

Answer (score 1):

This is working for me using the `@SlingObject` annotation, rather than `@Inject` and `@Source`. Theoretically they should be doing the same thing, but figured I'll add this an answer just in case it helps someone else as well.

```
@Model(adaptables = Resource.class)
public class Navigation {

  @SlingObject
  private ResourceResolver resourceResolver;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have invoked `<cq:defineObjects />` before adapting resource to model (`<cq:defineObjects />` should be in your global.jsp file which should be included on the beginning of each component)

Comment: It is being included as copied libs global.jsp into my personal global.jsp and sling models with normal injectors are working fine . Only ResourceResolver is returning null in my case.

Comment: try to add explicitly `<sling:defineObjects/>` next to the `<cq:defineObjects />`. 
in theory `<cq:defineObjects />` should provide objects from `<sling:defineObjects/>` but imo it is worth to try. 
may be it doesn't work because you changed `sling` taglib definition uri

Comment: added still the same issue persists , any alternative if u can suggest or give inputs

Comment: my last idea it to check what is produced by the `<cq:defineObjects />` tag
for this purpose you install [**AEM Dash**](https://github.com/Cognifide/AEM-Dash) package which gives possibility to decompile AEM classes
Install it, open `/etc/dash.html` page and decompile
` com.day.cq.wcm.tags.DefineObjectsTag` (to see how works `<cq:defineObjects />` tag)
keep it mind that this class should extend  `org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.taglib.DefineObjectsTag` class so check what it produced by this both classes (the second one should produce resourceResolver object)

Comment: Thanks Dawid , but i tried other way using @Self annotation , then adjusting required pom dependencies , so it worked that way .

Comment: @user3837000 please post an answer describing what you did. It's going to be much easier to find than these comments if anyone else has the same problem.